# Changing value of a global variable inside a function

Tags: python, function, boolean, global-variables, ipywidgets

I run in Jupyter-Notebook the following code:

```
from IPython.display import display
import ipywidgets as widgets

turn_on = 'Run'
turn_off = 'Skip'

skipp = True

button_exec = widgets.Button(description=turn_on)
display(button_exec)

def exec_clicked(b):
    global skipp
    if skipp:
        b.description = turn_off
    else:
        b.description = turn_on
    skipp = not skipp

button_exec.on_click(exec_clicked)
```

and whenever I press the button, the value of "skipp" doesn't change, but the destription of the button changes. I tried to run without the statement of the "global" but it doesn't work as well.

Comment: How do you know `skipp` doesn't change? Does the button description change?

Comment: Check your indentation in your actual file. Particularly, check if you might have accidentally mixed tabs and spaces. The code you posted doesn't display mixed tabs and spaces, but maybe the code you ran is different.

Comment: @user2357112 I verified it's value in the notebook, the button description changes.

Comment: @Codevan the value of skipp changes when I press the button. Is there a reason why you wouldn't wanna declare a global in a function?